# Prevent multiple clicks

Tags: android

This is my code for a custom view. I'm trying to prevent multiple clicks on this EditText but it stills open two EditStatusActivity screen. Why?

```
    setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            if(isClicked) {
                return;
            }               
            isClicked = true;
            setEnabled(false);
            setClickable(false);

            final Intent intent = new Intent(activity, EditStatusActivity.class);               
            intent.putExtra(STATUS, currentStatus);
            activity.startActivityForResult(intent, EDIT_STATUS_REQUEST_CODE);

            isClicked = false;
            setEnabled(true);
            setClickable(true);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

reset your  isClicked AND setEnabled on onActivityResult method

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);         
        isClicked = false;
        setEnabled(true); 
    }
```

As pablochan wrote:

> The `startActivityForResult` method is non-blocking. That means that
>   as soon as you start the `EditStatusActivity`, you immediately set the
>   `isClickable` variable to false, and that's why you're able to make
>   extra clicks.

You should either never set `isClickable` to true or set it to true in the `onActivityResult` method.

Comment: I had this type of problem before and another way of doing it is scheduling do reset the `isClicked` variable with timer 500ms in the future

Answer (score 0):

The `startActivityForResult` method is non-blocking. That means that as soon as you start the EditStatusActivity, you immediately set the `isClickable` variable to `false`, and that's why you're able to make extra clicks.

You should either never set `isClickable` to true after the first click or set it to true in the [onActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more option which I preffe.

When you handle Click event remove listener and restore it onResume.